# Readable recurring event string?

Tags: event

Is there an easy access to a readable recurring string from Apex? In the UI of the event, if it is recurring, you will see info like:

> Occurs every 1 week(s) on Sunday, Tuesday effective 06/20/2017 until 7/27/2017 From 2:00 PM until 3:00 PM

Do they assemble this on their end from all the recurrence fields? If they do, have they haven't made another field to store this text string?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct string, at least not for the day of the week, but there are ways of generating one. If you look at the [Object Reference for Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm), you'll see that you first need to determine if the `IsRecurrence` field is set to `true`. If it is, then you'll want to look at the following fields:

> **IsChild**
>
> Indicates whether the event is a child of another event (true) or not (false).
>
> For a child event, you can update IsReminderSet and ReminderDateTime only. You can query and delete a child event. If the objects related to the child event are different from those related to the parent event (this difference is possible if you use API version 25.0 or earlier) and one of the objects related to the child event is deleted, the objects related to the parent event are updated to ensure data integrity.
>
> **RecurrenceActivityId**
>
> Read-only. Not required on create. Contains the ID of the main record of the recurring event. Subsequent occurrences have the same value in this field.
>
> **RecurrenceDayOfMonth**
>
> Indicates the day of the month on which the event repeats. (Integer)
>
> **RecurrenceDayOfWeekMask**
>
> Indicates the day or days of the week on which the event repeats. This field contains a bitmask. The values are as follows:
>
> - Sunday = 1
> - Monday = 2
> - Tuesday = 4
> - Wednesday = 8
> - Thursday = 16
> - Friday = 32
> - Saturday = 64
>
> Multiple days are represented as the sum of their numerical values. For example, Tuesday and Thursday = 4 + 16 = 20.

**You'd need to work backward from any value contained in this bitmask to determine the string value to associate with it.**

> **RecurrenceInstance**
>
> Indicates the frequency of the event’s recurrence. For example, 2nd or 3rd.
>
> **RecurrenceInterval**
>
> Indicates the interval between recurring events. (Integer)
>
> **RecurrenceMonthOfYear**
>
> Indicates the month in which the event repeats. (picklist)

See the link above for more fields you can use to build a string about the event.

Comment: So I will have to query the recurrence parent (based on ReccurenceActivityId of child events) and get all that recurrence information (because from what I see, it is only set on the recurrence parent). Then construct a readable string of the recurrence rules?

Comment: That pretty much sums it up.